# How to connect at least 3 Wi-Fi at the same time?

Tags: network, wifi, airport, 802.1x

I'm helping a friend with a MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) with macOS Mojave v 10.14.6, to activate and connect at least 3 Wi-Fi interfaces at the same time.

First, a bit of context... We are in Venezuela with a very crappy internet connections, less than 1 Mpbs in AVG, so we are trying to make channel bonding in order to allow us to use multiple Internet connections simultaneously to optimize performance, we are using Speedify for macOS and it works like a charm!

**We have:**

- 2 Huawei E5573Cs-609 Hotspots with a SIM card with a mobile data
  plan.
- 2 Smartphones with hotspot functionality

**Total:** 4 Available Wi-Fi connections.

- 2 External USB Wi-Fi Adapters (TL-WL725N - Version 3).
- 1 MacBook's built-in Wireless card.

We have installed these [specific drivers](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201811/20181109/TL-WN725N_V3_181022_Mac_beta.zip) from [here](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wn725n/v3/#Driver).

Running the `ifconfig` command,

- `en0` stands for the built-in Wireless receiver (WI-FI).
- `en4` for one TP-Link USB dongle.
- `en5` for the another TP-Link USB dongle.

Thanks to the StatusBarApp (TP-Link's wireless network adaptor APP), located inside of `/Library/Application\ Support/WLAN/StatusBarApp.app/` we manage to active en4 and connect it to a network.

In theory we can active a "hardwareport" or "interface" running a this command:

`sudo networksetup -setairportpower en5 on`
But this is the output:

> en5 is not a Wi-Fi interface.
>
> Turning on the only airport interface found: en0

So this other command won't work:

`networksetup -setairportnetwork en5 <network> [password]`

We found `wpa_supplicant` inside a folder in the `/Library/Application\ Support/WLAN/StatusBarApp.app/` directory, but without `wpa_passphrase` exec.

But there is no problem, on my Linux computer I've generated a wpa_supplicant.conf with 4 blocks like this:

```
network={
        ssid="My_SSID"
        #psk="My_Passphrase"
        psk=psk_generated_here
        id_str="Network One"
}
```

But I'm not sure how to set up en0, en4, en5 to each network...

### EDIT:

As @nohillside requested, here is the output of `networksetup -listallhardwareports`, `ifconfig en4` and `ifconfig en5` commands:

```
mba:~ rob$ networksetup -listallhardwareports

Hardware Port: 802.11n NIC
Device: en5
Ethernet Address: 50:3e:aa:23:dc:d2

Hardware Port: 802.11n NIC
Device: en4
Ethernet Address: 50:3e:aa:23:ad:56

Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: 1c:36:bb:2f:c3:d2

Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN
Device: en2
Ethernet Address: 1c:36:bb:2f:c3:d3

Hardware Port: Thunderbolt 1
Device: en1
Ethernet Address: 9a:00:13:d9:e0:60

Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Bridge
Device: bridge0
Ethernet Address: 9a:00:13:d9:e0:60

VLAN Configurations
===================
mba:~ rob$ ifconfig en4
en4: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 50:3e:aa:23:ad:56 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
    status: inactive
mba:~ rob$ ifconfig en5
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 50:3e:aa:23:dc:d2 
    inet6 fe80::815:e1a5:3023:39aa%en5 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xd 
    inet 192.168.8.103 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.8.255
    inet 192.168.8.102 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.8.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
mba:~ rob$
```

We have more than 2 days Googling and trying a lot of stuff with no results (having >=3 active and running Wi-Fi connections) in order to merge it with Speedify (which perform its work very well).

How can we achieve this?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: [Multiple simultaneous wifi connections](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28473/multiple-simultaneous-wifi-connections?rq=1)

Comment: Hello @ankii thanks for answering! We looked at that link before. We already have the interfaces (`en0`, `en4` and `en5`) the problem is that `networksetup -setairportnetwork` says that ANY interface (hardware port) different than `en0` is not a a Wi-Fi interface. I mean, we can programmatically on/off and connect the built-in card  `en0` to a network using that command, but just that interface :-(

Comment: Can you add the output of `networksetup -listallhardwareports`, `ifconfig en4`, `ifconfig en5` to the question?

Comment: Hi @nohillside, done! Sorry for my late answer.

Comment: I thought Speedify was supposed to handle all of this for you. Have you contacted their support team?

Comment: @TJLuoma is not a Speedify issue but an OS issue. We can't connect our MacBook Air to 3 Wi-Fi. Speedify makes its works very well, when the Wi-Fi are active and connected, Speedify just makes the channel bonding. And yes, we already contacted the Speedify support team.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately I don't know how to help, but I was hoping that they would have run into this before.

Comment: Just a thought. Use your linux machine as a router. Hardwire to your linux machine. Share it's internet connection to your mac.